# ADAL Authentication Requires Device managed on Android

Tags: android, office365, adal, intune

I tried setting up our Android app to work with Intune and ADAL authentication. 
I added it to a managed play store in Azure. My test Android device shows up as compliant. I also added a Conditional Access that require the device to be compliant. Downloaded the app via company portal.

When I log in I'm getting prompted to enter email and password in a web view. Then it redirects me to the following screen:

[image]

When I click "enroll now" it opens to install company portal.

I also tried adding the following example app:
https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/Taskr-Sample-Intune-Android-App

Signed it and uploaded it to play store but getting the same error screen.

I have installed the Microsoft authenticator app but still the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had not configured our application to use a broker (Microsoft Authenticator or Company portal). Without configuring a broker the conditional access policy configured in AD won't work.

More information here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/leveraging-brokers-on-Android-and-iOS#brokered-authentication-for-android

And here, look for broker support:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android